# How to configure a Cloud Scheduler job to call a Cloud Run endpoint that allows unauthenticated calls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a Cloud Run service setup and I have a Cloud Scheduler job that calls an endpoint on that service.
The job sent a GET call (which have an header with a jwt and an api-key, necessary to certify the call to the endpoint) to the Cloud Run endpoint. I have already tried to test the endpoint locally, and it works. Maybe it is necessary a particular configuration for the scheduler to work?

When the job work, I can see from the log console on Cloud Run this:
[Cloud Run Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCfeU.png).

What can I do to fix this problem?
Thank you

Comment: What is the result of calling the endpoint from your desktop using **curl** or a similar tool?

Comment: the rusult is a jsonify response '200'.

Comment: The error is **500**. Your problem is not an authentication issue. Your problem is your app is crashing or failing to start. Review the Cloud Run logs. The screenshot is for Cloud Scheduler (I think).

Comment: Thank you. There was an error inside the endpoint the scheduler calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these [docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler) which walk you through creating or editing a service account for the Scheduler Job to use which is allowed to 'invoke' Cloud Run services.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: OIDC authorization and audience are the key

Comment: so there is no way to 'invoke' with cloud scheduler a cloud run service which allows unauthenticated invocations without use a service account?

Comment: Why would you want to expose an endpoint, that might cost you money to the public internet? Even when it's a matter of cents, using a service-account is by design the optimum.

Comment: Because the endpoint is not exposed: to access to the endpoint you need a unique api-key + a personal access token (this last composed by the backend)